# Button reset не работает в Opera, Chrom

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не работает функция button reset  в двух браузерах. 
Код в html

```
<form id="cscalc_form" role="form" action="/">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="toNumber" name="nonMajorityParentIncome" id="nonMajorityParentIncome" value="" placeholder="">
<span class="highlight"></span>
<label for="nonMajorityParentIncome">Net Income after Tax <a href="#" class="helpmark" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Enter the parent's net income after all taxes."></a></label>

</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="toNumber" name="nonMajorityOvernights" id="nonMajorityOvernights" value="" placeholder="">    
<span class="highlight"></span>
<label for="nonMajorityOvernights">Number of Overnights <a href="#" class="helpmark" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Enter the number overnights this parent spends with children."></a></label>
</div>

    <section class="cscalc_section section_results">
    <div class="row gutter-10 center-xs bottom-xs-30">
    <button class="col col-xs-auto button alt small btn-calculate" id="btn-calculate" onclick="doCalculations();"><i class="fa fa-calculator" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Calculate</button>
    <button class="col col-xs-auto button alt small btn-clear" id="btn-clear" onclick="clearButtons();">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <div class="text-xs-center">
    <p id="cscalc_result" style="display: none;"><span id="resultInput"></span></p>
    </div>
    </section>
    </form>


    function clearButtons() {
        jQuery("#btn-clear").bind("click", function () {
            $("#cscalc_form input[type=text], #cscalc_form textarea").val("")
        })
    };
```

Comment: 1) какие поля должен сбрасывать? В приведённом коде, такое ощущение, что часть кода просто отсутствует. 2) https://api.jquery.com/ready/ 3) Используйте или функцию для очистки, или jQuery bind. А то получается винигрет.

Comment: Где в примере элемент `#cscalc_form`? Зачем используете знак `~` в `~function clearButtons`?

Comment: @ Stepan Kasyanenko ##cscalc_form у меня вначале. Функция clearButtons работает в браузере Мозила, а в других нет.

Comment: `<input type="reset">` - если нужно все поля очистить в форме

Comment: А второй кнопке задайте `type="button"`, чтобы форма не отправлялась.